# Data Validation of a Filtered table

Tags: vba, validation, excel, filtering

I have a Data table with an Auto Filter (shown Below).

```
Sub Tariff_Filter()

    Dim columnNumber, tableRow, tableColumn, tableWidth As Integer
    Dim tableName, columnName As String

    tableName = "Tariff_Table"
    columnName = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

    'This clears the existing filter

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).Range.AutoFilter

    'Assign some numbers we need to know about the table to check the headers
    tableRow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).Range.Row
    tableColumn = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).Range.Column
    tableWidth = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).Range.Columns.Count

    'If a column title with the specified value does not exist VBA throws an error which we need to catch
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Search through the table column header row to find the specified column and assign the number to columnNumber
    columnNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(columnName, Range(Cells(tableRow, tableColumn), Cells(tableRow, tableColumn + tableWidth)), 0)

    'Apply the filter "1" to the found columnNumber
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName).Range.AutoFilter field:=columnNumber, Criteria1:="1"

    'Exit the sub otherwise the "error handling" will be provoked
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox columnName & "Please Specify Required Channel"

End Sub
```

As i cant seem to figure out how to get my combo-box's to show only the visible cells after filtering the table i was wondering if there is a way i can create a a validation box to show the visible cells or copy the visible data into a seperate table underneath. I can then use the validation box/ secondary table as a focus point for the combo-box's on the user-form.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you would like to have a data-validation drop-down list that updates as the table is filtered and only displays visible items for a given column.

You can do this by using the following formula in Data Validation (I'm assuming your table header row starts in A1 and it's col A you need to display):

=OFFSET($A$2,,,SUBTOTAL(103,TableName[column name]))

This formula expands from the starting cell (A2) by a specified height in number of rows. We are defining the height using SUBTOTAL with function number 103 - this means that the height is defined using COUNTA, but only on visible cells, so it will expand and collapse as the table is filtered.

Be aware: since the height is defined using a counta function, it will only count cells containing data, therefore if you have blanks in your table, the range will not be defined correctly. Also if you have any repeated data, these will be repeated in your drop-down box, this method will not condense them into a neat, unique list.

Hope this is helpful.
D